# Similar operation for Console.log in VB.Net?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Is there something like console.log in Javascript for Visual Basic?

For example, how can I do this with VB?

var monkey = "chimp";
console.log(monkey); //Logs "chimp" in the console.

Comment: Use breakpoints in Visual Studio.

Comment: `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine` if you're building a console app.  `MessageBox.Show` for a WinForms app.  But the debugger is the best way to check values in a .NET program.  You can put `debugger();` in JavaScript to step into the program from IE into the Visual Studio IDE as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the platform and application you are using and more importantly the purpose of the logging.

You can use the `Console` class which offers `Write` and `WriteLine` static methods. This will write your log to standard console. For a console application, this is the best choice:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Log text")
```

If you are using the log just for debugging purposes, you can use the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class with `WriteLine` static method. This class also offers a `WriteLineIf` method which accepts an argument of type `Boolean` and writes the log if the value passed for that argument equals to `True`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLineIf(x = y, "They are equal")
```

You can view the debug console output in Visual Studio's output window.